# How much of the SpaceChem Mobile campaign is duplicated from SpaceChem PC?

Tags: spacechem

I have SpaceChem for PC, and am considering purchasing SpaceChem Mobile, because one SpaceChem game just ain't enough.

On the other hand, I don't want to buy the game and then discover that all of the puzzles are the same.

**How much of SpaceChem Mobile is reused content from SpaceChem PC?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the same game more or less, but missing the "boss levels" (Defense).  But for the price, who can complain?  :)  It has ResearchNet so you can work w/new content on the go...

From [the Zachtronics site](http://www.zachtronicsindustries.com/coming-soon-spacechem-on-the-ipad/):

---

SpaceChem Mobile is a direct port of SpaceChem, meaning it’s almost exactly the same, but with a few notable differences:

- The controls have been reimagined for touch (an obvious change), including a new way to quickly place arrow instructions (hold a button, drag a path).
- The toolbar has been moved to the top to make it easier to place instructions.
- The main campaign does not include boss battles or the story and is easier to progress through (more optional pipelines, specifically).
- Video recording and forum signature generation are not available.
- It only costs $5.99!

ResearchNet is fully functional in SpaceChem Mobile and will receive new issues of the Journal of Reaction Engineering at the same time as the PC version of SpaceChem.

Comment: Good info. What does "more optional pipelines" refer to?

Comment: @AndrewMoylan I actually only have the PC version, so what I know comes from reading.  But my guess from that is it doesn't have anything to do with the pipes connecting reactors.  Rather it means on the planet map where you select levels, you are not forced to complete as many of those levels before you are allowed to move on.  *(So you can skip more and still go on to higher levels and next planets.)*